# Error when running a Webpack bundled Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, webpack, service-worker

I have a very simple application available at https://github.com/sbwrege2z/webpack-test.

Here's the code for the main application:

```
const UrlPattern = require('url-pattern');
const serviceWorkerRouter = require('service-worker-router');

const router = new serviceWorkerRouter.Router();

// THIS METHOD OF ROUTING DOES NOT CAUSE A PROBLEM:
router.get('/api/*', null);

// CAUSES BUNDLE TO BREAK:
router.get(new UrlPattern(/^\/api\/(.*)$/), null);

console.log('Hello world!');
```

When you run this file with "node src/index.js" you get the expected "Hello world!" output.

When you run the Webpack created bundle with "node dist/bundle.js" you get the error:

```
TypeError: argument must be a regex or a string
```

If you comment out the line with the "new UrlPattern(...)" the bundle will run without any issues.  Something with the regex method of defining the url pattern is causing this to break.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

---

**Update**

I know what is causing the problem.  I just haven't come up with a solution yet.

The UrlPattern constructor expects a string or RegEx as the first argument.

The Router get method expects the first argument to be a string or a URLPattern.  If the first argument is NOT an instanceof UrlPattern, it creates a new UrlPattern with the first argument.  I'm sure the assumption is that it's a string or RegEx, but it doesn't check.

During minification something happens to that the Router does not recognize the first parameter passed to the get method as a UrlPattern, so it tries to create a new UrlPattern with the first argument (which is a UrlPattern).  Since the first argument to the UrlPattern constructor is neither a string or a RegEx, an error is thrown.

Possible Solution:

Figure out how to configure WebPack's minify process so that the UrlPattern is recognized as an instance of a UrlPattern.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not necassarily a problem with the url-pattern module.  I added an index2.js file to the repository that has no references to the service-worker-router module, and the b.bundle.js created from that works fine.  I suspect it has something to do with the service-worker-router module.  As far as I can tell, the service-worker-router uses the same version of url-pattern that my project does --- 1.0.3.

Comment: May I ask what it is you are trying to do? It looks like the `UrlPattern` library is meant to check whether a given URL matches a particular regex pattern. I don't think it is intended to be used as a url formatting sort of deal – which is what looks like is going on here.

Comment: Sure.  I am building a cloudflare service worker that acts as a router.  It translates url's to locations of resources on AWS S3 storage.  To do this, I'd really like to be able to use regular expressions in the routing.  The supplied code is just a very simple illustration of the problem.  When I use regular expressions with the service-worker-router, I get problems with the generated webpack bundle that is uploaded to the edge.

Comment: The thing I'm trying to figure out is what about the bundling process breaks an application that works fine when not bundled?

Comment: I updated the repo.  There are 2 entry points (index.js and index2.js) and two bundles (bundle1.js and bundle2.js).  The only difference in the two apps is 1 line of code.  bundle2.js without that line works, and bundle1.js with that line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the import fixes the problem:

```
const UrlPattern = require('service-worker-router').UrlPattern;
```

No changes to the Webpack configuration are necessary.

Comment: For a little more info, even though the UrlPattern code was the same for both the required module and the Service Worker Router, they were 2 copies of the same code.  When bundling the code, these classes were assigned different names --- e.g. a and b.  Then when a route was defined with version b of the UrlPattern, this was not an instance of version a of the UrlPattern.  So the router tried to create a new UrlPattern with version b.  And the UrlPattern only allows a string or a regex.